# c# load program settings after reboot computer

Tags: c#, wpf, autostart

I have a problem with loading the settings to my program. After a system restart the program starts up automatically, but doesn't load the settings as it should. It does however load them when I run the application manually.

Starting the program with the system

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
rkApp.SetValue("Monitor", BaseDir+"\\Monitor.exe");
```

Class responsible for loading settings

```
class MySettings : AppSettings<MySettings>
{
    public string filePath = null;
    public string interval = "0";
}
public class AppSettings<T> where T : new()
{
    private const string DEFAULT_FILENAME = "settings.jsn";

    public void Save(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(this));
    }

    public static void Save(T pSettings, string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(pSettings));
    }

    public static T Load(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
    {
        T t = new T();
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            t = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<T>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
        return t;
    }
}
```

I'm using the following code to load my settings

```
MySettings settings = MySettings.Load();
string inter = settings.interval;
```

Why does the settings only load after restarting the application?

Comment: 1. The program will start up with the system, does not load settings from the file.
2. Turn off apps
3. Turn on the applications, the settings are loaded, do not know why in the first step does not load.

Comment: Try to use absolute path to the file (for example `DEFAULT_FILENAME = @"C:\myApplication\settings.jsn"`) instead of using only a filename. Maybe a working directory differs when the application is run by the system and the file is just not found. Please let me know if this solves Your issue.

Comment: I tried to do so: `private const string DEFAULT_FILENAME = basedir + "\\ settings.json";` but gets an error `Default parameter value for 'fileName' must be a compile-time constant`

Comment: To verify if this is the cause of the issue, just hardcode the whole path for testing. To use base directory from another string replace `const` with `readonly` keyword. Let me know if You need help making this change.

Comment: Try to set the current working directory using [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Or simply save your settings in the folder where they belong, in the AppData folder. Then you know where the settings are.

Comment: @Patrick I do not really understand

Comment: How to use `return default(T)` in Load method

Comment: The two most likely causes of your problem: You don't get your settings because either the path is different between autostart up and manual start up, OR your settings file is unavailable to autostart up because it starts under a different account from when you do manual start up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may occur if the application's working directory is different when it's run by the system than if You're running it manually.

To fix this You can specify the absolute path to the settings file.
You can do this by replacing the line:

```
private const string DEFAULT_FILENAME = "settings.jsn";
```

with:

```
private const string DEFAULT_FILENAME = @"C:\MyApplicationFolder\settings.jsn";
```

or:

```
private static readonly string DEFAULT_FILENAME = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "settings.jsn");
```

Please let me know if need more help with this.

You can also use other suggestions mentioned in the comments for Your question.

UPDATE

If You cannot use `Application.StartupPath` property for some reason, You can also use:

```
private static readonly string DEFAULT_FILENAME = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "settings.jsn");
```

I also haven't noticed that You use this path as default value in Your methods. To make it work You can try to change `WorkingDirectory` as suggested by **Patrick** in the comments or just use null as default and assign default value in the method's body like this:

```
public void Save(string fileName = null)
{
    AssignDefaultSettingsFilePathIfEmpty(ref fileName);

    File.WriteAllText(fileName, (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(this));
}

private void AssignDefaultSettingsFilePathIfEmpty(ref string fileName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: I change this `private readonly string DEFAULT_FILENAME = BaseDir + "settings.jsn";` It did not help

Comment: What is `BaseDir` in Your case? Please take a look at the code sample I've put in the answer that detects where the application file is located and adjusts the path accordingly.

Comment: `public static string BaseDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

Comment: I suupose `Location` includes also the filename. Please try `private static readonly string DEFAULT_FILENAME = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "settings.jsn");` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I try this, the same error `Default parameter value for 'fileName' must be a compile-time constant` using: `private static readonly string DEFAULT_FILENAME = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "settings.jsn");`

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed You use it as default value in the methods. You can't do it this way. You can try to change the working directory as *Patrick* suggested in the comments or use empty value as default for the parameter and then assing the correct one inside each of the methods.

Comment: I put `private static readonly string DEFAULT_FILENAME = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "settings.jsn");` to the `t = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<T>(File.ReadAllText(DEFAULT_FILENAME));` but still the same problem with load settings

Comment: Please show the value of the `DEFAULT_FILENAME` somewhere in the application window, so You can see it. This way You should be able to verify if the path is correct.

Comment: I print the `DEFAULT_FILENAME` value on application start with system and the value is empty. After restarting the application `DEFAULT_FILENAME` returns correctly catalog

Comment: Try to use this: `private static readonly string DEFAULT_FILENAME = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "settings.jsn");` and also print it in the window for verification.

Comment: With manual startup path exists. As the program starts with the start value system is not...

Comment: So, do You mean that when the application is run by system You can see only "settings.jsn" printed in the window  or there is nothing printed at all? You should be able to see at least the file name printed, even if there is an issue with the path.